# Appcelerator studio via mac os: Invalid "--device-id"

Tags: ios, macos, appcelerator

I've got an error when I tried run application in Appcelerator on Mac.

Before I installed XCode 9.2+iOS 11.2

Appcelerator successfully found xcode and available lists of simulators:

[image: list of simulator]

Result of execution:

```
[ERROR] :  Invalid "--device-id" value "15E7FD44-6368-43A3-BB93-075D4145B652"
Available iOS Simulators:
For help, run: titanium.js help build
```

Also command "info -t IOS" gives contradictory result about the empty list of the available iOS Simulator.

```
$ appc ti info -t iOS 

Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 7.0.2
Xcode
  9.2 (build 9C40b)
    Install Location          = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer 
    iOS SDKs                  = 11.2
    iOS Simulators            = 11.2
    Watch SDKs                = 4.2
    Watch Simulators          = 4.2
    Supported by TiSDK 7.0.2.GA = yes
    EULA Accepted             = yes
    Teams                     = none

iOS Development Certificates
/Users/desktopadmin/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db
  xxxx@xxxx.xx (xxxxx)
    Not valid before          = 4/5/2018 4:30 PM
    Not valid after           = 4/5/2019 4:30 PM

pple WWDR Certificate
  Apple WWDR                  = installed

Development iOS Provisioning Profiles
  application
    ...
    Date Created              = 4/5/2018 4:27 PM
    Date Expired              = 4/5/2019 4:27 PM
    Managed                   = No

iOS Simulators None <--------this line is seemed strange
```

Problem not just in simulator - I've tried to connect a real device, but problem the same.

- Axway Appcelerator Studio 5.0.0.201712081732
- Titanium SDK 7.0.2
- iOS 11.2 (also tried 11.3, 11.0)
- XCode 9.2 (also tried 9.3 from AppStore)

Any idea?

Comment: try running xcode select: `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/` and then try running the `appc info` again, it should start listing simulators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've solved problem after:

1. Using advice of @Rene Pot (thnx a lot):

   > sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/
2. Updating macOS and Appcelerator module (CLI, TiSDK, and other Plugins)  till last version. I guess it was incompatibility of the concrete versions.
   Compatible version:

   - macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
   - XCode 9.3
   - iOS SDK 11.3
   - Appcelerator 5.0.0.20181208 with updates of May 4, 2018

I'm not sure which of 2 steps have really helped, but it works!

Comment: I also encountered the exact same problem today and after doing almost everything from update to reinstall xcode studio node npm... nothing worked out... but the terminal command as 1st solution worked in milliseconds and it solved out this nightmare issue

Answer (score 3):

You have to run xcode once manually and accept the certificate and also it downloads and install some components. Only open Xcode and if it asks to accept certificate, then accept it and it will ask for components, accept that also. I hope it will help you.